# Flutter ExpansionTile children as Gridview?

Tags: dictionary, gridview, flutter

Is it possible to get Flutter  ExpansionTile children as Gridview?
Currently I am getting ListView using this code.

```
children : myData.map((data) {return MyWidget()}).toList()
```

I want ExpensionTile children as GridView not ListView. I am Making a Shopping App where ExpensionTile is Category and I want children SubCategories as GridView.

Comment: Yes you can use ExpansionTiles for Gridview but can you provide more information on what you wish to achieve?

Comment: Simply I want ExpensionTile children as GridView not ListView. I am Making a Shopping App where ExpensionTile is Category and I want children SubCategories as GridView.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my attempt at it:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            ExpansionTile(title: Text("Category 1"), children: <Widget>[
              GridView.count(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("SubCategory 1"),
                    Text("SubCategory 2"),
                    Text("SubCategory 3"),
                    Text("SubCategory 4"),
                    Text("SubCategory 5"),
                    Text("SubCategory 6"),
                  ])
            ]),
            ExpansionTile(title: Text("Category 2"), children: <Widget>[
              GridView.count(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("SubCategory 1"),
                    Text("SubCategory 2"),
                    Text("SubCategory 3"),
                    Text("SubCategory 4"),
                    Text("SubCategory 5"),
                    Text("SubCategory 6"),
                  ])
            ]),
            ExpansionTile(title: Text("Category 3"), children: <Widget>[
              GridView.count(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("SubCategory 1"),
                    Text("SubCategory 2"),
                    Text("SubCategory 3"),
                    Text("SubCategory 4"),
                    Text("SubCategory 5"),
                    Text("SubCategory 6"),
                  ])
            ])
          ]),
        )
```

[image: AppDemo]